# Scope of private static variable in non static class

Tags: c#, asp.net, static

I know that, a static property can persist its value as long as the application remains running. Will it be same for a private static field inside non static class

```
public class A
{
   private static int B;

   public int GetSession()
   {
     return B++;
   }
}
```

In above class i have a private static field. Will calling `GetSession()` method will provide number of times the `GetSession()` accessed?

Comment: If the containing class is `static` or not has absolutely no effect on a `static` member at all. `static` means `static`, this is **shared accross all instances**. Apart from this you can simply try it out by creating different instances and look if all of them jhave the same value for your static field.

Comment: _"In above class i have a private static property"_ nope, you have a private static field

Comment: @HimBromBeere, Got it, Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Rango, Updated the question. :) Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `B` is `static` it'll be *shared* between *all* sessions; the *thread-safe* (what if *two* sessions are trying to access / increment it *simultaneously*?) implementation is

```
   public int GetSession()
   {
       return Interlocked.Increment(ref B);
   }
```

**Edit:** If we want to emulate `B++`, not `++B` (and return `B` *before* incrementing - see Jeppe Stig Nielsen's comment) we can just subract `1`:

```
   public int GetSession()
   {
       // - 1 Since we want to emulate B++ (value before incrementing), not ++B
       return Interlocked.Increment(ref B) - 1;
   }
```

Comment: His original code had `return B++;`, _not_ `return ++B;`. Does he want the incremented value returned, or the value before incrementation?

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: Nice catch! Thank you! Probably, the easiest way to emulate `B++` instead of `++B` is to subtract `1`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will provide the number of times the `GetSession()` method was called.

It will be the total over *all* instances of `A`.

Note that it is not thread safe, so if your application has multiple threads potentially calling `GetSession()` concurrently, the count may be wrong. See Dmitry Bychenko's answer. This is no problem if all your instances of `A` are being called from the same thread.

Also note, that if your application has several AppDomains, each AppDomain will have a separate static field. So then it counts only invocations from within the same AppDomain, regardless of which instance the calls went through.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will still return the number of times B was accessed. It's still `static`. Adding private does not change this. And making the class `static` means that an object cannot be instantiated for that class, therefore, everything in the class would need to be `static`. But the variable will still behave the same.

Comment: that `private` Accessor was the confusing part for me, thanks for clearing it up.